# Is there a way to list no of Jobs per GitHub Organization in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to find a way to list no of Jobs per GitHub Organization ? I am able to get the github jobs configured on a controller with

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).findAll { !it.isDisabled() }.each { multibranchpipelines ->
    println(“Active jobs within ” + multibranchpipelines.getFullName())
    multibranchpipelines.getItems().each { branch ->
        if (branch.isBuildable()) {
            branch.getAllJobs().each { job ->
                if (job.isBuildable()) {
                    println(“\t” + job.getFullName())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but how do i get the jobs per github org. Can i make changes to above script and acheive this ? Any input is appreciated.